# How to groupby a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like this

```
StudentID   Grades
101 A
101 C
101 B
102 B
102 C
```

I need the output as below as another dataframe

```
StudentID   Grades
101 A,B,C
102 B,C
```

How to do this in pandas. When i groupby, it returns a groupby object and not a dataframe

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'StudentID': [101,101,101,102,102],
        'Grades': ['A','C','B','B','C']
     })

df.groupby('StudentID').Grades.agg(",".join)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the `DataFrame` you want via the returned `groupby` object:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'StudentID': [101,101,101,102,102],
        'Grades': ['A','C','B','B','C']
     })
grouped = df.groupby('StudentID')
for student_id, df_student in grouped:
    print 'ID:', student_id
    print df_student
```

Output:

```
ID: 101
  Grades  StudentID
0      A        101
1      C        101
2      B        101
ID: 102
  Grades  StudentID
3      B        102
4      C        102
```

You can also access the `DataFrame` with a specific key

```
print grouped.get_group(101)
```

which will return the `DataFrame` with all `StudentID` being equal to 101.

Comment: Can i get the output of Grades as comma seperated values? What i need is an output dataframe like below:  StudentID Grades
101 A,B,C
102 B,C